# Как добиться обновления суммы в таблице БД

Tags: php

Прошу, подскажите, у кого есть возможность - Как добиться обновления суммы в таблице БД? Код рабочий, уведомления `txt` приходят, и запись в таблицу `платеж` идет. Всё четко.
В таблице `пользователь` тишина. Этот код я пробовал по-разному: и определять `id` пользователя, и делать выборку перед записью, и много других вариантов. Результат один - запись в таблицу происходит, а обновление записи - нет.
Как надо сделать, подскажите, пожалуйста?

```
$notification_type = $_POST["notification_type"]; 
$operation_id = $_POST["operation_id"];
$amount = $_POST["amount"];
$currency = $_POST["currency"];
$datetime = $_POST["datetime"];
$sender = $_POST["sender"];
$codepro = $_POST["codepro"];
$label = $_POST["label"];
$sha1_hash = $_POST["sha1_hash"];
$test_notification = $_POST["test_notification"];

$hash = $notification_type . '&' . $operation_id . '&' . $amount . '&' . $currency . '&' . $datetime . '&' . $sender . '&' . $codepro . '&' . $notification_secret . '&' . $label; //формируем хеш

$sha1 = hash("sha1", $hash); //кодируем в SHA1

//Ниже - проверка на валидность
if ( $sha1 == $sha1_hash ) {
echo 'OK';
} else {
echo 'error';
}              

// Ниже - отладка - запись в файл testlog.txt переданых данных с ЯД.
 {
$test_wr = fopen ('testlog.txt', 'a+');
fwrite ($test_wr, "$notification_type - тип нотификации\r\n$operation_id - ид операции\r\n$amount - сумма\r\n$currency -Код валюты\r\n$datetime - дата+время\r\n$sender -отправитель\r\n$codepro - наличие кода протекции\r\n$label - метка платежа\r\n$sha1_hash - переданый проверочный хеш\r\n$sha1 - расчитаный хэш\r\n$test_notification - тестовая нотификация\r\n");
fclose ($test_wr);
}

        {
    
        //Обновляем данные по счету пользователя 
        if(isset($_POST['amount']))
        mysqli_query($link,"UPDATE user SET summa=summa+".$_POST['amount']." WHERE id_user='".$_POST['label']."'"); 
        
        if(isset($_POST['label']))
        mysqli_query($link,"INSERT INTO plateg (summa, id_user, typ, data, opis)  VALUES ('".$_POST['amount']."', '".$_POST['label']."', 1, NOW(), 'Пополнение кошелька через Яндекс.Деньги')");
        return true;          
        
        }       
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Если храните сумму строкой, то пробуйте это:

```
mysqli_query($link,"UPDATE user SET summa= CAST((CAST(summa as INT(11)) + $_POST['amount']) as VARCHAR(11)) WHERE id_user='".$_POST['label']."'");
```

Comment: Попробуйте заменить на summa= summa + CAST($_POST['amount']) AS DECIMAL(10,2))

Comment: возможно sql некорректно принимает число с плавающей точкой в переменной $_POST['amount']

Comment: Все, спасибо за подсказки. В поле сумма заменил - double на int.